# Changing Java from OpenJDK to SunJava

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, path, jdk

I want to change OpenJDK to SunJava in my ubuntu linux desktop , i have downloaded the "jdk-7.tar.gz" from sun's website, but there problem is how to make the system to use the newly downloaded java ? I tried adding the new jdk/bin/java to my PATH ( from .bashrc ) but that seem not to work (cause probably OpenJDK's path is inside my PATH variable as well , so the system checks that first)

Here's my JDK7 : /usr/lib/jdk7/bin/java
Here's what $(which java) outputs : /usr/bin/java
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Try `mv /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/java.old; ln -s /usr/lib/jdk7/bin/java /usr/bin/java`

Comment: I did create the soft link you've given me , but i'm getting this :cannot execute binary file
(I've given it the permission , the error is not because of not having the permission) any idea why ?

Comment: To undo the link (if you haven't already) use `mv /usr/bin/java.old /usr/bin/java` and overwrite.

As to why? Check the architecture of the jdk7 you downloaded against the architecture of your system (or, if you built it from source, check the build output). Also, see if there is a Java 7 repo/package available for your system's package manager of choice; that's a good way to eliminate build-related problems, and if you really want hand-installed/hand-configured customizations, you can start from a package install and work backwards to figure out where the manual process went wrong.

Comment: I've undone the link already , but what's caught my eyes is that why the symbolic ( or soft , whatever ) link is not working :(
Um how can I check the architecture of the JDK ?( cause really that might be the problem since i'm using the source which I've found in my friend's hard disk ! )

Comment: Specifically (per my last suggestion), try this: http://brunoreis.com/tech/intalling-java-ubuntu-natty/

Comment: Nah ! It was the architecture yeah , Thanks for bringing that up !